# RailsのActiveRecordのdeleteとdestroyの返り値の仕様が知りたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

- [ActiveRecordのdestroyメソッドの挙動について調べてみた | task blog](http://task-blog.net/2015/03/31/how-action-destroy-of-rails-method/)
- [第6章 ユーザーのモデルを作成する | Rails チュートリアル](http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/modeling-users?version=4.0#sec-database_migrations)

> 奇妙なことに、destroyはcreateと同じようにそのオブジェクト自身を返します

上記以外に返り値について言及しているところを見つけるところができませんでした。
削除成功の場合と失敗の場合での返り値の仕様が知りたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

destory の返り値は、参考URLにあるとおり、基本的に freeze された object ですね。
但し、before_destroy が失敗したときのみ、false。

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L173-L187

```
# There's a series of callbacks associated with #destroy. If the
# <tt>before_destroy</tt> callback throws +:abort+ the action is cancelled
# and #destroy returns +false+.
# See ActiveRecord::Callbacks for further details.
def destroy
  raise ReadOnlyRecord, "#{self.class} is marked as readonly" if readonly?
  destroy_associations
  self.class.connection.add_transaction_record(self)
  destroy_row if persisted?
  @destroyed = true
  freeze
end
```

一方で、delete は何がどうなっても、freeze された object を返すようです。
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L167-L171

```
def delete
  self.class.delete(id) if persisted?
  @destroyed = true
  freeze
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails4以降であれば、destroy!を使うことで例外を発生させることができるようです。

参考：http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Comment: 残念ですが、純粋に返り値が気になっております。

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/ や http://railsdoc.com/ を見る限り、失敗についての仕様は存在しないようです。よって、実際の実装が現在の仕様ということになると思います。